# Is a Muslim man extreme if he lowers his gaze with every woman?

Tags: practical-islam

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Is it Ghuloo (Exaggeration) if a 27 year old unmarried man lowers his gaze in front of every non mahram woman even if she is an old lady / mother of many kids?
His friends call him extreme and advise him to "tone" down and make eye contact with atleast the old women.

Comment: Define "extreme" else this sounds a bit subjective.

Comment: extreme as in too strict or exaggerated in social situations.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Meaning too much

Answer (score -1):

Lower your gaze does not mean in every occasion ,

In Islamic terminology it refers to :

Refraining from looking at people’s ‘awrahs, which includes the beauty of a non-mahram woman.

Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him) said in Majmoo’ al-Fataawa (15/414):

Allaah, may He be glorified and exalted, has enjoined us in His Book to lower the gaze, which is of two types: refraining from looking at ‘awrahs and refraining from looking at the site of desire.

The former refers to a man refraining from looking at the ‘awrah of another person.

And yes, i believe it is too much to lower gaze in social situation. How can you talk to a woman without seeing their eyes? How can you do that at the office while at work?

Lowering gaze is required if you see her awrah accidentally.

Comment: But isn't the voice of the woman also awrah? 

Also, i heard an incident of Prophet Musa (as). 


Ibn ‘Abbās and ’Umar stated: When she (his future wife) said that, her father asked her, “How do you know that he is strong and trustworthy?” She replied, “He lifted a rock that no less than ten people could lift. And when I led him home by walking in front of him, he said, ‘Walk behind me. When you need me to change the path, throw a pebble on that path and I will know to change direction.’” This shows the chivalry of Mūsā, his chastity and his respect for women.

Comment: If Prophet Musa (as) considered it a necessity to be so cautious, would it be considered "too much" for a sinful Muslim in this day and age of outrageous fitnah, to refrain from making any eye contact?

Comment: The story mentioned above is found in Tafseer Ibn Katheer (Surah Qasas) 
with a reference given to [At tabari 19 : 562-564]

Comment: Also, to add, the "women" mentioned in the question above are not wearing any hijab/ niqab, Thereby exposing their necks.

Comment: @Abdulla I don't know what tradition you're following but in my country, talking to others without looking in their eyes is considered as an insult, even woman. Hijab in here is just to cover everything but face. I wondered, how does prophet Muhammad (pbuh) talking to a woman guest? or to his sahaba's wife? If everything in women is awrah then nobody should interact or meet them at all. Too much is too much. Yes, i am aware of the women mentioned above is non-mahram, but you should look to my answer, awrah is the site of desire. I'm 28 yo married, i have no desired in women's hair or voices.